# HP Pavilion dm1: Slow download, fast upload

Tags: windows-7

I just bought a HP Pavilion dm1 netbook yesterday, and the internet was really slow. I ran a speed test and I'm getting 0.4 Mpbs down, 4.5 Mpbs up. My other laptops on the network get 10+ Mpbs down. I made sure to update to the latest drivers, and updated the firmware of the router, and I see no improvement.

I've had this problem since the minute I opened the laptop, and I've no other problems on other laptops connecting to the same network.

HP technical support suggested I buy one of their new routers -.-

Is there something else I can do?

I'm running Windows 7 with a Linksys WRT160N router, and the network adapter is a Ralink RT5390.

I'll check periodically for questions if you guys need more information from me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For any future readers of this question: I fixed the problem on my own by changing the encryption type from AES to TKIP. It was just a guess, but my download speed is now 20 Mpbs, up from 0.4 Mpbs.